# flowable integration break jhipster maven integration tests

Tags: java, jhipster, liquibase, flowable

I have created a jhipster micro service with maven and add some entities using import-jdl. Everything was working perfectly fine with maven integration tests automatically generated. 
Now I would like to integrate flowable and after adding `flowable-spring-boot-starter-basic:6.3.1`.

But I get error:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: missing table

Versions:

- jhipster version 5.0.1
- flowable version 6.3.1

What i understand is that liquibase configuration of flowable is creating problems on jhipster liquibase configuration. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

flowable desactivate by default liquibase with spring boot.

You have to add the property liquibase.enabled = true